# Is it possible to apply pagination during generating report with JasperReports?

Tags: java, sql, pagination, jasper-reports, out-of-memory

We're using Jasperreports 6.1.0 to generate our reports. To generate the reports, we provide a SQL script. Jasper executes the script and fills the template with the generated data.

Now as the data has grown, our system has started giving Out of Memory error while executing report. This is due to large amount of data getting loaded in memory due to large amount of data getting returned from SQL query.

My question is: Is there a way to direct Jasper to load data from query using pagination? for e.g., Jasper should perform the following steps:

1. Load 100 records at a time
2. Write these records to report
3. Load further 100 records
4. Update the report
5. Repeat steps 1 to 4 until there is no data.

Comment: please rename question header. It's "How to make Jasper pagination" or something. It is possible, you need to setup paging on the report and supply page values to query. Did you try executing what tutorials on jasper say? for example: http://helptodeveloper.blogspot.com/2010/02/jasper-reports-with-pagination.html

Comment: Thanks for your response but for that we'll have to redesign the report. Can jasper do this for single page report?

Comment: yes, you can change your query to accept size & start from, and that would make custom pagination. You would then use value from your paginator to reflect the page you're on. More on that in "sql pagination". That would require you to manually implement what is provided automatically by jasper, though.